# How to find nal,sps,pps,vps from H265 stream?

Tags: h.264, video-processing, live555

I am developing `h265 parser` and give parsed data to `LIVE555` stack, but not able to find `NAL`, `SPS`, `PPS`, `VPS` from data.
I have taken reference from the following link:
[H264 Parser](http://lists.live555.com/pipermail/live-devel/2012-April/014955.html)

So my question is: How to find VPS, SPS, PPS, NAL from h265 data?

Comment: Have you identified the start codes?

Comment: May be this https://github.com/rayl/live555/blob/master/liveMedia/H264or5VideoStreamFramer.cpp?